# Curl генерация тела запроса

Tags: php, post, curl

Здравствуйте !
Подскажите пожалуйста , можно ли как-то посмотреть какой POST запрос генерирует curl по переданным параметрам?

Comment: Пример в студию!

Comment: Так отправьте запрос на свой тестовый url, в котором пропишите var_dump($_POST) и запишите в файл или посмотрите ответ через curl. А вообще можете сами формировать строку post через http_build_query

Comment: @ilyaplot, а если запрос генерируется для multipart/form-data ?  Браузер возвращает :

 `------WebKitFormBoundaryibLm7G5cqxCOuAFy
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="file"; filename="1-g-0-032-oz-silver-valcambi-bullion-bar-999-rev.jpg"
Content-Type: image/jpeg


------WebKitFormBoundaryibLm7G5cqxCOuAFy
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="scrid"

32482346-7100587438898460646
------WebKitFormBoundaryibLm7G5cqxCOuAFy--`



вопрос в том , можно ли посмотреть что будет генерироваться при отправке на сервер , что бы сравнить запрос и ответ .

прошу прощение за форматирование.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Нет, к сожалению, такой нативной возможности у расширения `curl` нет. Зато можно отправить запрос куда-нибудь на подконтрольную вам программу и посмотреть, что в точности пришло. Например, самое простое, через `nc` открыть порт:

```
nc -l -p 12345
```

Затем в коде заменить URL на этот локальный адрес:

```
$ch = curl_init('http://127.0.0.1:12345');
curl_setopt_array($ch, [
    CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
    CURLOPT_POST => true,
    CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => ['foo' => 1],
]);
$response = curl_exec($ch);
```

При запуске этого кода на консоли с `nc` появится точный отправленный запрос:

```
melkij@melkij:~$ nc -l -p 12345
POST / HTTP/1.1
Host: 127.0.0.1:12345
Accept: */*
Content-Length: 139
Expect: 100-continue
Content-Type: multipart/form-data; boundary=------------------------05be5d432625f809

--------------------------05be5d432625f809
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="foo"

1
--------------------------05be5d432625f809--
```

Comment: Благодарю! Помогли

Answer (score -1):

Используйте опцию -v

```
curl -v google.com
```