# Отправка POST запроса и перенаправить пользователя

Tags: php, post, curl

Ситуация:
У нас есть страница index, на ней пользователь нажимает кнопку submit, его отправляет на страницу processing.php где она должна перенаправить на another.php самого пользователя с POST параметрами.
Так вот как осуществить перенаправление пользователя с POST параметрами?

Comment: Ничего не понятно. У вас клавиша запятая естъ? Если да, то почему не пользуетесь.

Comment: Изменил, если что не понятно спрашивайте

Answer (score 0):

Вероятно вы ищете HTTP/1.1 код ответа `307`. Он сообщает браузеру, что неплохо бы повторить запрос с теми же параметрами (включая метод), по адресу в заголовке `Location`.

Не уверен насчёт поддержки этой спецификации в браузерах.

Согласно [rfc2616](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec10.html), если метод не GET/HEAD - браузер должен спросить у пользователя повторить ли запрос на новый ресурс.

Comment: Спасибо за быстрый ответ, но мне нужно что бы файл произвёл некую обработку информации (добавил новые поля), и только потом перенаправил

Comment: Почему бы не спроксировать запрос без участия пользователя?

Comment: Потому что на странице на которую его перенаправят в конце, пользователь должен будет продолжать разные действия

Comment: Ну так и отдайте ему последнюю страницу. Для чего редиректы?

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/539644/curl-%D0%B3%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%8F-%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%B0-%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%B0

Comment: Практически такая же проблема