# POST запрос CURL, возвращает 404

Tags: php, http, curl

Нужно отправить POST-запрос банку для авторизации. Запрос отправляю CURL, но возвращается 404 код. Что делаю не так?

Запрос нужно отправить в таком формате:

```
POST /secure/token HTTP/1.1
Authorization: Basic строкаАвторизации
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded

Request Body:
grant_type=authorization_code&code=<код авторизации>&redirect_uri=<URL возврата>
```

Отправляю запрос через CURL:

```
$params=[
   'grant_type'=>'authorization_code',
   'code'=>$code,
   'redirect_uri'=>$uri
];
$headers = [
   'POST /secure/token HTTP/1.1',
   'Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
];
$curlURL='https://sso.tinkoff.ru';       
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,$curlURL);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPAUTH, CURLAUTH_BASIC);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERPWD, $user . ":" . $pass);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,http_build_query($params));
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, true);

if(curl_exec($ch)) {
   $server_output = json_decode(curl_exec($ch));
}
```

Что делаю неправильно?

**UPD:**
Разобрался, в чем дело. Дело было в https. Как только получил SSL сертификат — заработало. Спасибо за помощь!

Comment: https://www.jino.ru/help/faq/problems/error-404/

Comment: Обратите внимание, что вы выполняете HTTP-запрос дважды - по числу вызовов `curl_exec`. Который из них даёт 404? Что отвечает первый? Вам запрос надо отправить на `https://sso.tinkoff.ru/` или на `https://sso.tinkoff.ru/secure/token`? Мой локальный curl с таким кодом хочет идти именно на первый адрес.

Answer (score 2):

По документации видно, что `url` должен быть `https://sso.tinkoff.ru/secure/token`, а у вас идет `https://sso.tinkoff.ru/` поменяйте урл и все заработает

**upd:** 
и оставьте только так

```
$headers = [
   'Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
];
```

и этот кусок поправьте

```
if(curl_exec($ch)) {
   $server_output = json_decode(curl_exec($ch));
}
```

на

```
$curl_res = curl_exec($ch);
if($curl_res) {
    $server_output = json_decode($curl_res);
}
```

а то вы два запроса делаете

Comment: а я просто поменял урл и получаю 400, вот `HTTP\/1.1 400 Bad Request\r\nServer: spray-can\/1.3.3\r\nDate: Sat, 21 Oct 2017 11:00:43 GMT\r\nrequestId: 8c6ad9969c252bae1a5b`, так как у меня логина и пароля нет, жалуется на авторизацию

Comment: у вас просто в браузере открывается `https://sso.tinkoff.ru/secure/token`?)

Comment: Поменял строки и т. д., действительно, если неправильно аутентифицироваться, тот 400 ошибка. А если правильно, то 404, так как неправильный request. Как добиться нужного формата запроса?

Answer (score 2):

`libcurl` штука хорошая, но при работе с ней понимать структуру HTTP запросов и ответов всё равно требуется.

Заголовки запроса вам даже из-за включенного `CURLOPT_VERBOSE` должны быть видны и там отчётливо виден запрос

```
POST / HTTP/1.1
```

Вместо `/secure/token`. Почему? Потому что `CURLOPT_URL` имеет приоритет над `CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER`. `Content-Type` же необходимый выставит `CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS` самостоятельно.

Как итог - вам не нужен `CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER` вообще. Библиотека проставит все заголовки самостоятельно.

---

Как уже написал в комментариях - каждый вызов `curl_exec` осуществляет HTTP запрос. Т.е. ваш код делает два запроса, при том отбрасывает результат первого. Да и результат второго запроса тоже отбрасывает. Потому что `json_decode` дальше по коду требует чтобы ему был передан JSON документ. На заголовки HTTP-ответа он отреагирует единственно возможным способом - решит что это не JSON-документ и ответит NULL. А вы никуда ответ не сохранили и вообще не проверили, был ли корректно выполнен запрос через `curl_errno`/`curl_error`

Сторонняя система вполне может считать коды авторизации одноразовыми.

Я очень надеюсь, что вы не системой платежей занимаетесь. Для работы с деньгами у вас очень сильно не хватает ни понимания своего собственного кода ни опыта отладки - это отчётливо видно по комментариям.

```
// TODO: write to log outcoming request

$ch = curl_init();

/// curl_setopt*

$response = curl_exec($ch);
if (curl_errno($ch)) {
    throw new \RuntimeException('Curl error #'. curl_errno($ch) . ': ' .curl_error($ch));
}
$requestInfo = curl_getinfo($ch);
$responseBody = substr($response, $requestInfo['header_size']);
$responseHeaders = substr($response, 0, $requestInfo['header_size']);

// TODO: записать в лог выполненный запрос с полным $requestInfo, $responseBody и $responseHeaders

// TODO: проверить $requestInfo['http_code'] согласно документации API. >=500 явно ошибка, остальные смотреть документацию что должны отвечать

$decodedResponse = json_decode($responseBody);
if (is_null($decodedResponse)) {
    throw new \RuntimeException('response is not JSON');
}

// TODO: проверить декодированную структуру на наличие необходимых элементов
```

Comment: Спасибо за подробный ответ. К счастью — это не система платежей, а просто тестовый проект. Проблема действительно в неправильном request. Как сделать правильный запрос?

Comment: Посмотреть на осуществляемый curl'ом и сравнить с тем, что требует документация внешней системы. (если документация там актуальная, что далеко не обязательно)

Comment: подскажите как увидеть само тело запроса?
Через CURLOPT_STDERR вывел в файл, но там самого тела запроса нет, есть только Content-Length

Comment: Тело запроса - это в точности то, что передано в CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS (если передана строка как у вас). Если передаётся массив - то https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/539720/203622